# UISegmentedControl selected tintColor on viewLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uisegmentedcontrol

I am attempting to set the tintColor and selected tintColor for a UISegmentedControl.

So far everything works fine except for the fact that when the view first loads, even though I call my method to set the tintColor (and it executes) the tintColor doesnt actually get set correctly until the first click.

It does appear however, as if *something* is happening because i am trying to set the color to black with white selection, and the default colors are a tad darker.

any ideas on how to actually modify the colors for the load?

```
//some code
-(void)viewDidLoad
_segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
[self segmentedControl:_segmentedControl];
```

---

```
//set color method
- (IBAction)segmentedControl:(BaseSegmentedControl *)sender
{
//change the color of every subview(segment) you have
 for (int i = 0; i < [[sender subviews] count]; i++ )
{
    if ([[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:i]isSelected] )
    {
        [[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:nil];
        [[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }
    else
    {
        [[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:nil];
        [[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: Side note - it is a bad idea to dig in the private subview structure of standard controls. Your code could easily break in a future update of iOS.

Comment: its the only way ive seen to set the individual colors for a segmentcontrol post ios6

Answer (score 5):

I think you've probably put your uisegmentedcontrol to the navigationbar. When you do this, the UISegmentedControl is loaded before your view, so setting tint color is of no use. I find a solution here:

```
 self.segmentedControll.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal;
```

as the document says:

> When this property’s value changes (either by the view’s value
>   changing or by one of its superview’s values changing), -the system
>   calls the tintColorDidChange method to allow the view to refresh its
>   rendering.

Adding this line to your viewDidLoad method, this will cause the segmentedcontroll to redraw.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set it in `-viewWillAppear`  I think the views are not setup fully yet in `-viewDidLoad` Also don't forget  `[super viewDidLoad];` in `-viewDidLoad`